# How to Factory Reset Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: command-line, sudo

I would like to know how to reset Ubuntu to default and if it resets my terminal.

I tried to put in a command to make it if I messed up my password it would tell me something sassy. I did that in the /etc/sudoers/ file, and I messed it up. I can't use any sudo command and I would like to reset my terminal, or my whole Ubuntu set up. I tried to initiate super-user with `su` and I put in my password correctly, as this is a private computer, and it told me `su: Authentication Failure`.

If you could please tell me how I could undo my mistake I would appreciate it. This is a new computer so Factory Reset would not delete anything important. I will provide anymore detail that you may request, if I know it. I am new to Ubuntu and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as 'Factory Reset' for the same reason there is no 'Restore Partition': Those features are meant to preserve your Product Key (or equivalent). Product Keys track paid software. Ubuntu does not have one.

The equivalent of a 'Factory Reset' in the Ubuntu world is to simply dig out your original install media and reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

If you messed up your `/etc/sudoers` file you should be able to boot with your live USB and copy it over.

Completely reinstalling Ubuntu should not be necessary in such a case.

When you say "sassy" I assume you mean [sudo insults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837558/where-are-sudos-insults-stored/837614#837614).

Answer (score 0):

`su` requires `root`'s password rather than yours, and `root` is unlikely to have a password on Ubuntu, so `su` is generally unusable by itself.

You can try `pkexec` in place of `sudo` (as in `pkexec visudo`) and undo your changes to `/etc/sudoers`.